# Remove duplicated elements (not lists) from 2D list, Python

Tags: python, pandas, list

I would like to delete all the elements from list of lists that appear more than once and am looking for a smoother solution than this:
[Removing Duplicate Elements from List of Lists in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46018429/removing-duplicate-elements-from-list-of-lists-in-prolog)

I am not trying to remove duplicated lists inside of the parent list like here:
[How to remove duplicates from nested lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55349986/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-nested-lists)

Consider this Int:

```
list = [
[1, 3, 4, 5, 77],
[1, 5, 10, 3, 4],
[1, 5, 100, 3, 4], 
[1, 3, 4, 5, 89], 
[1, 3, 5, 47, 48]]
```

Desired output:

```
new_list= [
[77],
[10],
[100], 
[89], 
[47, 48]]
```

Thanks. I am going to use this in Pandas: the new_list will serve as a new column with unique values on each row compare to the original column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be sleeker ways, but this works:

```
from collections import Counter

mylist = [
[1, 3, 4, 5, 77],
[1, 5, 10, 3, 4],
[1, 5, 100, 3, 4], 
[1, 3, 4, 5, 89], 
[1, 3, 5, 47, 48]]


flat = [y for x in mylist for y in x]    
count = Counter(flat)
uniq = [x for x,y in count.items() if y == 1]
new_list = [[x for x in y if x in  uniq] for y in mylist]
```

which gives

```
[[77], [10], [100], [89], [47, 48]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for bi,lst in enumerate(l):
    for el in lst:
        for i in range(len(l)):
            if bi != i:
                if el in l[i]:
                    print(f'element:{el}')
                    print(f'passing over list:{l[i]}')
                    l[i].remove(el)
                    try: l[bi].remove(el)
                    except: continue
```

that one is not that useful but I see that usually other answers(including your linked posts) uses another modules so I tried different approach.